# What to check when shell_exec() does not work?

Tags: php, shell, iis, permissions, shell-exec

I have the following code running in an application on IIS:

```
<?php
    echo "begin test";
    $temp = shell_exec('whoami 2>&1');
    print_r($temp);
    echo "<br/>end test";
?>
```

This outputs:

```
begin test
end test
```

This means that `shell_exec` did not execute. Additionally no exception was thrown, nor was there any warning outputted.

What do i need to check to ensure this executes properly?

Edit: `disable_functions` in php.ini is blank

Comment: could you try to give cmd.exe iis_iusrs and iusr execute permission?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal the button to add users to cmd.exe permissions are greyed out in properties->permissions

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is open your `php.ini` file and find the part labeled `disable_functions`. Make sure that the list of disabled functions does not include `shell_exec`. You can also dump this information to a browser screen via `phpinfo`. That has the advantage of allowing you to do a ctrl-f for `shell_exec`. (Be sure to turn the dump off again once you've grabbed what you need.)

In any case, if you're enabling `shell_exec` on a server where it was disabled, proceed with extreme caution, especially if you're sharing the environment with others. There is likely a very good reason why it's turned off. For example, it's common for popular packages to have vulnerabilities discovered, and a shared hosting admin who can't convince their boss to ban said packages might disable `shell_exec` as a way to temporarily allow clients to keep running those insecure packages until the packages have actual fixes. For obvious reasons, turning `shell_exec` back on could be extremely dangerous.

Anyhow, I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, the value of `disable_functions` in php.ini is blank

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be something to do with the PHP version. Updating from PHP 5 to PHP 8 resolved the issue.